# What is the correct way to uninstall "run-time" eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, runtime

When creating eclipse plugins I check them by running it as a eclipse application and it work.(it is installed as a plugin in that run time eclipse instance). But it seems that these testing plugins do not automatically remove from that run time eclipse application instances. When I stop running it and run another eclipse plugin, the previous one too exist in that run time instance  of eclipse. That makes things crashing. So I want to know how to remove those run-time plugins from eclipse run-time instances(when run as eclipse application).

Comment: `Run Configurations` -> `Eclipse Application` there is `Clear` checkbox, try with that.